# Slice properties from objects and counting

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Is it possible to slice single property from array of objects like

```
[{"name":"Bryan","id":016, "counter":0}, {"name":"John","id":04, "counter":2}, {"name":"Alicia","id":07, "counter":6}, {"name":"Jenny","id":015, "counter":9}, {"name":"Bryan","id":016, "counter":0}, {"name":"Jenny","id":015, "counter":9}, {"name":"John","id":04, "counter":2}, {"name":"Jenny"    ,"id":015, "counter":9}];
```

I'm trying to slice `name` from every object and count number of the same elements (there are 3 objects with name Jenny) in order to achieve the following structure:

```
[{"name":"Bryan","Number":2},
{"name":"John","Number":2},
{"name":"Alicia","Number":1},
{"name":"Jenny","Number":3}]
```

Comment: Hi Cory, yes, it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hash table as a reference to the counted names.

```js
var data = [{ name: "Bryan", id: "016", counter: 0 }, { name: "John", id: "04", counter: 2 }, { name: "Alicia", id: "07", counter: 6 }, { name: "Jenny", id: "015", counter: 9 }, { name: "Bryan", id: "016", counter: 0 }, { name: "Jenny", id: "015", counter: 9 }, { name: "John", id: "04", counter: 2 }, { name: "Jenny", id: "015", counter: 9 }],
    grouped = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.name]) {
        this[a.name] = { name: a.name, Number: 0 };
        grouped.push(this[a.name]);
    }
    this[a.name].Number++;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to ignore the `id` and `counter` props already present?

You could create an object to keep track of the unique names, and convert back to an array in the end:

```js
var data = [{"name": "Bryan",  "id": 016,  "counter": 0}, {  "name": "John",  "id": 04,  "counter": 2}, {  "name": "Alicia",  "id": 07,  "counter": 6}, {  "name": "Jenny",  "id": 015,  "counter": 9}, {  "name": "Bryan",  "id": 016,  "counter ": 0}, {  "name": "Jenny",  "id": 015,  "counter ": 9}, {  "name": "John",  "id": 04,  "counter": 2}, {  "name": "Jenny",  "id": 015,  "counter": 9}];

var result = data.reduce(function(result, item) {
  if (!result[item.name]) {
    result[item.name] = {
      name: item.name,
      counter: 0
    };
  }

  result[item.name].counter += 1;
  
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(Object.keys(result).map(function(key) { return result[key] }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot. We create a dictionary of names with their counts called `nameDict`, and iterate through the list to count them.

```js
var arr = [{"name":"Bryan","id":"016", "counter":0}, {"name":"John","id":"04", "counter":2}, {"name":"Alicia","id":"07", "counter":6}, {"name":"Jenny","id":"015", "counter":9}, {"name":"Bryan","id":"016", "counter":0}, {"name":"Jenny","id":"015", "counter":9}, {"name":"John","id":"04", "counter":2}, {"name":"Jenny","id":"015", "counter":9}];
var nameDict = {};

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    var name = arr[i].name;
    if(nameDict[name] == undefined){
        //haven't encountered this name before so we need to create a new entry in the dict
        nameDict[name] = 1
    } else {
        //otherwise increment the count
        nameDict[name] += 1
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(nameDict));
```